# Does $S_n$ refer to an object, or a class?

Tags: group-theory, definition, symmetric-groups

In typical algebra textbooks, the elements of the structures presented are explicitly defined: for example, the n-th Symmetric Group, $S_n$ may be defined as containing precisely the permutations on the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, with function composition as its binary operation.

However, this is not a given, and another author may choose to define $S_n$ as containing permutation matrices, or using $n$-tuples, or whatever.

Thus, there appear to be all these $S_n$'s floating around, which is contrary to ordinary phraseology (i.e "Let $S_n$ denote **the** n-th symmetric group"). What is meant by such a phrase is something along the lines of: "let $S_n$ denote a group isomorphic to anything else one might imaginably call $S_n$, where in the context of where it will be used, the precise elements of the group do not matter."

But, I would say that this is an incorrect use of the word "the", and a more appropriate word would be "a". However, this all rests on what you believe: whether $S_n$ refers to a class of isomorphic groups, or whether it picks out a very specific "canonical" representation of it. So: which of the two is it?

Comment: As you correctly notice, there is an abuse of notation going on here. Whether the author refers to *the* group of permutations of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$, or to any other group that happens to be isomorphic it, ultimately can only be inferred from the context. What you need to know is how to transfer properties from one to the other (via isomorphism). The same abuse of notation happens regularly for tensor products, for polynomial rings (do the indeterminates matter?), and even for the set $\mathbb{N}$ (any set that satisfies the Peano axioms, or just one?).

Comment: Analysts are just as bad as algebraists: they speak of "the" real line, although "real numbers" might be Dedekind cuts in the rational line, or equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers, or equivalence classes of ordered pairs of positive real numbers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I've ever seen an author *define* $S_{n}$ as the set of $n \times n$ permutation matrices, although if you have this set of matrices you may call the set $S_{n}$.

To me, $S_{n}$ is the set of bijections on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ equipped with an operation of function composition. Now, if I have the set of bijections of $\{a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{n}\}$ I may call this $S_{n}$ because it's clearly canonically isomorphic to the first object. Or if I have the set of permutation matrices as mentioned. But I think the ambiguity comes not from the fuzziness of what $S_{n}$ is, but rather that it is common to refer to two things as being "the same" when we really mean they are isomorphic in a clear fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right ,it is a misuse of the word "the"in the sense of the object satisfying some displayed property . You could say for a set A , any set of n objects, that S(A) (or $S_n(A)$ ) is THE set of all bijections of A . That would satisfy me .